# Creating a Facebook Activity Stream via Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm looking to create a custom Facebook plugin for my website. Basically, what I want is the "Like Box" just without the stuff at the top, mostly because I think it looks silly.

I know that I can do this via JavaScript, I just have no idea how to ACTUALLY do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try giving a visit to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in javascript without asking your users to log into your site first.
To access this data from the api you need to make an authenticated call and you can't store your access token in the front end without exposing it.

You can however perform the necessary calls on the server and then render your own activity feed.

Comment: Exactly, I'm wanting to call the FB server and have it return my FB Activity feed. I just don't know how to do that!